# what is the difference between is-a and has-a?

Tags: python

I'm learning python and I have to fill in blanks with is-a or has-a and I'm not exactly clear on it. So I need the next examples explained why they are what they are.

Here are the examples. The fill in the blanks are the ##??'s.

```
## Animal is-a object (yes, sort of confusing) look at the extra credit
class Animal(object):
    pass
## ??
class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name):
        ## ??
        self.name = name
## ??
class Cat(Animal):

    def __init__(self, name):
        ## ??
        self.name = name
## ??
class Person(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        ## ??
        self.name = name

        ## Person has-a pet of some kind
        self.pet = None
```

Comment: Found this tutorial on [`learnpythonthehardway.org`](http://learnpythonthehardway.org): [Exercise 42: Is-A, Has-A, Objects, and Classes](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex42.html)

Comment: That is what I am learning but the explanation he gave wasn't to clear to me.

Comment: @Robᵩ, the question is what is the difference between is-a and has-a.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are searching for:

> An Animal **is-an** object
>
> A Dog **is-an** Animal
>
> A Dog **has-a** name
>
> A Cat **is-an** Animal
>
> A Cat **has-a** name
>
> A Person **is-an** Object
>
> A Person **has-a** name
>
> A Person **has-a** pet

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now. It just didn't come as fast to me when it was in code form. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The technical term for this is "Inheritance" ("is-a") versus "Composition" ("has-a").

There's a good deal of debate over which is better in any given circumstance. For the classic `Car` model of OOP, you could have:

```
class Car(object): # everything inherits from object in Py3
    # stuff related to being a car

class TwoWheelDrive(Car):
    # This car has two wheels that drive, so maybe
    def accelerate(self, vector):
        for wheel in [self.front_left_wheel, self.front_right_wheel]:
            wheel.RPM += vector

class FourWheelDrive(Car):
    def accelerate(self, vector):
        for wheel in [self.front_left_wheel, self.front_right_wheel,
                      self.rear_left_wheel, self.rear_right_wheel]:
            wheel.RPM += vector

my_car = FourWheelDrive(color='red',speed='super fast',coolness='very')
my_car.accelerate(float('inf')) # runs FourWheelDrive().accelerate(float('inf'))
```

Or you might build interfaces that the car HAS rather than different kinds of car that all ARE other cars.

```
class Wheel(object):
    # would probably have properties like RPM, traction, etc

class TwoWheelDriveInterface(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.front_left_wheel = Wheel(*args)
        self.front_right_wheel = Wheel(*args)
        self.rear_left_wheel = Wheel(*args)
        self.rear_right_wheel = Wheel(*args)
        self.wheels = [self.front_left_wheel, self.front_right_wheel,
                       self.rear_left_wheel, self.rear_right_wheel]
    def accelerate(self, vector):
        for wheel in [self.front_left_wheel, self.front_right_wheel]:
            wheel.RPM += vector

class FourWheelDriveInterface(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        # same as TwoWheelDriveInterface. In fact these could both
        # inherit from a common DriveInterface class and override
        # accelerate! (that is, both TwoWheelDriveInterface and
        # FourWheelDriveInterace ARE-A DriveInterface)
    def accelerate(self, vector):
        for wheel in self.wheels:
            wheel.RPM += vector

class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, color,speed,coolness,two_wheel_drive=False,*wheelargs):
        self.color = color
        self.speed = speed
        self.coolness = coolness
        if two_wheel_drive:
            self.driveinterface = TwoWheelDrive(*wheelargs)
        else:
            self.driveinterface = FourWheelDrive(*wheelargs)
        self.accelerate = self.driveinterface.accelerate # bind the methods together

my_car = Car(color='red',speed='very fast',coolness='very',two_wheel_drive=True)
my_car.accelerate(float('inf')) # runs TwoWheelDriveInterface().accelerate(float('inf'))
```

Another common example is a zoo. You might have many animals e.g.

```
class Animal(object):
    # attributes all animals have. Name, species, color, sound, etc?
class Kangaroo(Animal):
    # override attributes from Animal to make them specific to Kangas
class Lion(Animal):
    # see above
class Hyena(Animal):
class Monkey(Animal):
class Chimp(Monkey):
    # Chimps are-a monkey, which is-an Animal
class Bear(Animal):
    # etc etc ad nauseam, however....

class Zoo(Animal): # NO!
```

A Zoo is not an animal. It may have several of the same traits as an Animal, and may even make the code seem to be cleaner at first glance. After all, "DRY" right? We can override the things we don't need. However this is clearly a case for composition, not inheritance. A Zoo HAS animals, it is not, itself, an animal

```
class Zoo(object):
    def __init__(self, zoo_name, zoo_location, zoo_animals):
        self.name = zoo_name
        self.location = zoo_location
        self.animals = zoo_animals
        # zoo_animals in this case should be a list of Animal objects

ny_zoo = Zoo("New York Zoo", "New York", [Bear(), Lion(), Chimp(), Kangaroo()])
# ny_zoo HAS the following animals:
# # Bear
# # Lion
# # Chimp
# # Kangaroo
```